# images enlarging and text shifting

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a HTML signature to be used in Outlook; I'm new to this world and I'm of course losing pieces behind while doing this assignment.
I wrote from scratch this cose by taking inspiration by many other email signature on the web. The main two problems are that for some reasons in certain email clients my html mi-behaves strangely by automatically resizing images and moving paragraphs here and there even if I set them with the `position` tag.
Can someone please help me? I'm losing my mind since a month!
Thanks from the heart in advance

[signature in outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec8jl.jpg)

[signature in another email client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7BF2.jpg)

The code:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Firma PublyTeam</title>
</head>
<body style="width:autopx;height:auto;font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#000000">
<table style="table-layout:fixed;width:470px;height:110px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:170px;height:110px">
            <p style="width:130px;height:auto;position:relative;left:51px;bottom:25px;font-size:12pt;margin:0px">Walter&nbsp;Vecchioni</p>
            <p style="width:115px;position:relative;left:64.5px;bottom:21.8px;font-size:9pt;font-weight:lighter;font-style:italic;margin:0px">Co-Founder&nbsp;&&nbsp;CEO</p>
            <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/59ffe2_3052d562a30b48268214f6e42f94d7d0~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_808,h_168,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/Publyteam-R.png" alt="Logo Publyteam" style="width:170px;height:auto;position:relative;top:21.5px;left:4px;margin:0px">
        </td>
        <td style="width:271px;height:110px;font-size:9pt;font-weight:lighter; border-left:solid 2px #c2cd46">
            <p style="width:271px;position:relative;left:9px;bottom:17px;margin:0px">+39 039 614102&nbsp; +39 335 717422</p>
            <p style="width:280px;position:relative;left:9.3px;bottom:13px;margin:0px">Strada dei Boschi, 7 - 20852 Villasanta (MB) - Italia</p>
            <p style="position:relative;bottom:9px;left:10px;margin:0px"><a href="mailto:walter@publyteam.it" style="color:#c2cd46">walter@publyteam.it</a></p>
            <p style="position:relative;bottom:4px;left:10px;margin:0px"><a href="https://www.publyteam.it" style="color:#c2cd46">www.publyteam.it</a></p>
            <p style="position:relative;left:10px;top:7.3px;margin:0px">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/publyteamsrl/"><img style="width:18px;height:18px;padding:-1px;padding-right: 5px" src="https://i.ibb.co/dPKpgy6/fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/publyteam-srl/"><img style="width:18px;height:18px;padding:-1px;padding-right:5px" src="https://i.ibb.co/RCyws3L/in.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
                <a href="https://instagram.com/publyteam?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y="><img style="width:18px;height:18px;padding:-1px;padding-right:5px" src="https://i.ibb.co/M64CZYc/tt.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPSqd-A7LMMVwEYfzTjreGQ"><img style="width:18px;height:18px;padding:-1px" src="https://i.ibb.co/pnNB0TC/yt.png" alt="YouTube"></a>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that you should not upload images with code in your question. Put the code in code blocks. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You probably don't know how to use positions in this case. Consider using margins, paddings and learn about displays.

Comment: use a tool like https://mjml.io to generate HTML that works in all email clients.

Comment: From your code I can see that you used **absolute** positions and width and units for images and paragraphs, using [relative units](https://thecssworkshop.com/lessons/relative-units) can help you to have a responsive layout that may render better in different mails.

Answer (score 0):

Some html/css doesn't work in emails and different email providers work differently which can be frustrating. You can check what does and doesn't work on [caniemail.com](https://www.caniemail.com/) which is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had a look there but it confirmed that everything used in my code is supported in outlook for Mac! thanks for the website tho it's very useful!